# Set_Transient to end at midnight

Tags: transient

I want to set a transient, but that transient to expire at midnight.

How can I calculate the time until midnight in PHP for use in that transient definition?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to be that specific? If you need something to occur at a very specific time I don't think a transient would be appropriate.

Comment: Its a contest. I want to save theres a contest in progress, but that contest has to end to a specific date (given in the wp-admin). So when we are at the day where the contest end, that transient must end at midnight, and not at whenever that transient was set.

Comment: Like the problem if I was to setup a 24h transient, is if, for some reason, the transient resets a 11PM, i'm stuck with it active until 11PM the day the contest must be gone.

Comment: that looks like complicated. it would be easier to store the contest end time and to compare it at the current time. and time calculation is not WordPress related, it's PHP `strtotime("tomorrow")`

Comment: A transient is for holding data that expires, so I don't see how that's relevant for this situation, because there isn't any data that needs to expire or be deleted. How were you going to use this transient? Where are you checking it's value/expiration?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want this lines ?

```
$midnight_time = strtotime('tomorrow') - time();
set_transient( 'transient_name', $transient_datas, $midnight_time);
```

`$midnight_time` represent the seconds before midnight happens.

You can ask your server to curl a page with a random parameter if you have cache to be sure your transient is consumed with a `cronjob`.